# Firebase Authentication Error with Polymer Starter Kit

Tags: firebase, polymer-1.0, firebase-authentication

I am trying to use the polymer-fire elements to manage sign-ins on my website, built with Polymer Stater Kit. When clicking a button the **signInWithPopup** method is called on the firebase-auth element. Although the popup then appears, the link opened in the popup is wrong, which leads to a 404 error.

Since I don't know what causes the error I have created a [git repository](http://github.com/DiiLord/polymer-auth-error), where you can look at my code an d try it out

Comment: I cannot reproduce the problem you describe with your code. Clicking the link shows the Google sign-in view, and then the user info in the header bar after logging in. What link do you see?

Comment: I just see "about:blank" and uncaught network errors in the console

Comment: What OS and browser versions? What are the network errors?

Comment: I use ubuntu 16.04 LTS and chrome 53. The network error is that it can't find lausboehl.firebaseapp.com/src/lb-_.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was actually to add the following line to sw-precache-config.js:

```
navigateFallbackWhitelist: [/^(?!\/__)/, ' /getProjectConfig/'],
```

This prevents the service worker from trying to intercept the auth request.

Answer (score 1):

If you read the description from https://beta.webcomponents.org/element/firebase/polymerfire/firebase-auth it tell that you need to be carefull not to intercept request with prefix __ on your service worker if you using Firebase hosting to deploy your app. I put `ignoreUrlParametersMatching:[/^__/]` in my sw-precache-config.js like describe here https://github.com/GoogleChrome/sw-precache#ignoreurlparametersmatching-arrayregex

Try to access your web also from different browser. Or restart your browser. It works on me when I try it in Canary after fail on Chrome like you.

Comment: Any solution for this?